# plugins implementation asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, plugins, mef, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am trying to build an mvc application in modular fashion and I am open to any suggestions eg (Areas,MEF) etc..
Each module must be it's own dll EG(News,Admin,etc...) including all the views-controllers-scripts etc...

Before you ask of course I have googled and I have found many many posts but very very old.
I have also found that open source projects like NopCommerce use plugins.

I have tried to follow it but I get lost in other things it does,I was hoping for a streamlined version and how all hooks together and take it from there. EG SamplePlugin1-SamplePlugin2 and all the core stuff

Has anybody build a framework that uses plugins in an asp.net mvc5 app /or has a link to a project for me to have a look?

thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

NopCommerce is best to follow.

Go for just one plugin in it to start with. For example ShippingByTotal.

You need to have install configure methods for configuration.

Register it in dependency register. and then see how it is being called.

You can even reference discount plugins in nopcommerce.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Do you happen to have a small sample all stripped out that I can easily follow?

Comment: you can download shipping.bytotal plugin with source code and look at how it is hooked.